# Why did they not create the Indoraptor with a 'mother' the first time?

Tags: jurassic-world, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*, we see Henry Wu and Eli Mills talking about how they need Blue's DNA to create another Indoraptor, and that this one will need a mother, which Blue will serve as.

Why didn't Mills just have Wu create another Velociraptor like Blue to serve as the current Indoraptor's mother? That would have saved them the need to hunt Blue down.

In the junior novelization, it says that the mercenaries lost a lot of men to Blue. That could have been avoided if they had done what I said above. The question is referring to the current Indoraptor, nicknamed 'Ripper' by a youtuber.

Comment: Are you asking why they decided not to create the mother after the child?

Comment: yes. Why would they do that?

Comment: Surely it’s obvious why they wouldn’t create a “mother” after the fact? No imprinting, younger mother than child, no bond, etc.

Comment: sorry, I meant 'why wouldn't they make the mother before the child' I did not read your comment thoroughly

Comment: I voted not to close, but I agree the question is very unclear.  Do "another Indoraptor" and "current Indoraptor" refer to the same one?  Besides, they don't *need* Blue to serve as the mother, they need Blue's **DNA**; once they _have_ Blue, she can serve as the mother.

Comment: I should edit it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They wanted Blue's personality to rub off on the hatchling it would raise.  Just cloning Blue would be nature not nurture and they wanted nurture.  The more obvious question is why they didn't just use a hand puppet for the new ones to imprint on like how endangered birds get raised.

Comment: any sources for this, or is that just your opinion?